# Wamp and PhpMyAdmin not working

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, wamp

Following up from this question : [Mod Rewrite is giving me a hard time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12852962/mod-rewrite-is-giving-me-a-hard-time)

I'm trying to access phpmyadmin now in Wamp. It gives me a 404 that it isn't even there. I've tried and tried to research this. I don't have skype or anything like it on.

I do have an .htaccess file in my localhost/rs folder from that other question. I've read to change the ports, but it doesn't seem to help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I once had an issue where changing the ports would result to not finding phpmyadmin.
turned out, when I tried to surf towars it, it would automatically insert the wrong portnumber after  "127.0.0.1::". Make sure this is the port you set it on in your configuration files.

Make sure your htaccess' rewrite base is ok too. if it's in your "rs" folder, the rewrite base is "/rs/".

and next time, add your .htaccess's codes please.

also make sure it's .htaccess (with the dot)

Comment: But see, I didn't change the ports.

Comment: when I didn't it still happened to me. so your URL doesn't change to 127.0.01::8080?